# SQL Server: Return both records where one column is different

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find, from one table.  All the records where one column does not match.  I also need the  dates to follow certain circumstances based on the unmatched entry.

EXAMPLE:

```
record     COL1|COL2|COL3|  COL4  |  COL 5
1)          A    B    X    1/20/13   1/20/13
2)          A    B    Y    1/15/13   1/16/13
3)          B    D    X    2/14/13   2/16/13
4)          B    D    Y    2/15/13   4/09/13
```

What I need is (using record 1 & 2 as example):

- COL1 = COL1 AND COL2 = COL2
- COL3 <> COL3 (In COL3 only exists the entry X or Y.
- COL4 on record 2 is >= COL5 on record 1

In other words; I need all records where COL1 AND COL2 are duplicated BUT COL3 is unique; AND ALSO the record with Y must have COL4 >= record with X COL5 -7days

Comment: That basic boolean logic. You will find the answer here, but you will learn nothing. Try it yourself, it's not hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e9e6/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([record] int, [COL1] varchar(1), [COL2] varchar(1), [COL3] varchar(1), [COL4] date, [COL5] date)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([record], [COL1], [COL2], [COL3], [COL4], [COL5])
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'B', 'X', '2013-01-20', '2013-01-20'),
    (2, 'A', 'B', 'Y', '2013-01-15', '2013-01-16'),
    (3, 'B', 'D', 'X', '2013-02-14', '2013-02-16'),
    (4, 'B', 'D', 'Y', '2013-02-15', '2013-04-09'),
    (5, 'C', 'E', 'X', '2013-02-14', '2013-02-16'),
    (6, 'C', 'E', 'Y', '2013-01-15', '2013-02-09')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND
                        t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND  
                        t1.col3 <> t2.col3 AND
                        t2.col4 >= dateadd(dd,-7,t1.col5)
WHERE t1.col3 = 'X'
UNION
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND
                        t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND  
                        t1.col3 <> t2.col3 AND
                        t2.col4 >= dateadd(dd,-7,t1.col5)
WHERE t1.col3 = 'X'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e9e6/1/0)**:

```
| RECORD | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |       COL4 |       COL5 |
|--------|------|------|------|------------|------------|
|      1 |    A |    B |    X | 2013-01-20 | 2013-01-20 |
|      2 |    A |    B |    Y | 2013-01-15 | 2013-01-16 |
|      3 |    B |    D |    X | 2013-02-14 | 2013-02-16 |
|      4 |    B |    D |    Y | 2013-02-15 | 2013-04-09 |
```